# distinguish two attributes having the same name

Tags: php

I have 2 tables **affilie** and **avantage** and every one has an attribute named **id**, I made a query using left join. how I can distinguish those tow id having the same name when I want to use them.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM affilie af left join avantage av on af.id = av.id WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";
$req = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($req);
```

Comment: You use the table prefixes `av` and `af`: `av.id` and `af.id`

Comment: You have SQL injection, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @LozCherone ... and yet another irrelevant comment in a misled crusade. As usual you didn't read the question.

Comment: @scrowler, @HamZa: The table prefixes show up in the JOIN clause, but not in `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alias them on the SQL level:

```
SELECT
  af.id AS afid,
  af.somefield AS somefield,
  -- ...
  av.id AS avid,
  av.otherfield AS otherfield
  -- ,...
FROM
  ...
```